# Proving a function is the identity map on $U$

Tags: complex-analysis

or $|g(z+a)-a|\leq|k*z|$. I think that we know $k = 1$ from plugging in: f(a).

I am missing that final step. I am also not completely sure if we can apply Schwartz to $f(z)$ since it may not act on the open unit disc centered at the origin.

Comment: The formula $g(z+a)-a$ does not work as it does not make a function of $D$ onto $D$ a priori. But the idea is good. You need a holomorphic bijection $h$ of $D$ which sends $a$ to $0$. Then consider $g(z)=h^{-1}(f(h(z))$ and apply the Schwarz lemma.

Comment: Yes, Mobius transformations are the key. But this one does not work. [See here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusTransformation.html). Edit: I found a better reference, so I've updated the link.

Comment: No. This does not work. The map you wrote does not preserve the unit disk in general.

Comment: If you use the appropriate Mobius transformation I linked to (its inverse actually), the map $g$ defined above will fix $0$ and $h^{-1}(b)\neq 0$. Since it goes from $D$ to $D$, Schwarz lemma implies that $g(z)=e^{i\theta}z$. And since it fixes a nonzero point, actually $g(z)=z$. Now it is easy to deduce from that that $f(z)=z$.